# Use `seq` and print in haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell, io, monads, seq

I know that this is a little bit tricky but i wonder why it doesn't work!

```
module Main where

sillyDebug :: Int -> Int -> Int
sillyDebug x y =
    (print x) `seq` (x + y)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (sillyDebug 1 2)
```

while its ideal is the same as

```
sillyDebug = (trace (show x) False) `seq` (x + y)
```

Is it related to lazy evaluation or side effect in haskell?
https://hackhands.com/lazy-evaluation-works-haskell/

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Most of your imports are irrelevant, here. `sillyIO` is defined nowhere. `sillyDebug = (trace (show x) False) \`seq\` (x + y)` doesn't even compile. And describe the problem you're facing. What did you expect? What do you get?

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault :3

Comment: This problem is about the difference between *evaluating* an expression and *executing* a monadic action, but I think it’s also worth making a note about `seq`. ``a `seq` b`` doesn’t exactly force evaluation of `a`. It generates a dependency between thunks, so *if* `b` is evaluated, then `a` is too. ``print (snd (x `seq` y, z))`` never evaluates `x` because it never evaluates `y`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775528/why-cant-haskell-be-tricked-into-performing-io-operations-by-using-strict-evalu .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merely evaluating some `IO` action doesn’t do anything at all. You can think of `IO` sort of like a really big sum type of all the possible side-effectful things Haskell *can* do, even if it isn’t actually implemented like that at all. Something like this:

```
data IO a where
  PutStrLn :: String -> IO ()
  ReadFile :: FilePath -> IO String
  ExitWith :: ExitCode -> IO a
  ...
```

One of the `IO` constructors in this theoretical visualization would be a `Sequence` constructor, with a type signature like this:

```
  Sequence :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

This constructor is used to implement `>>=` for the `IO` type.

Inside of GHC is a magical function called `magicallyExecuteIO` with type `IO a -> a`, which coordinates for each action to actually perform its corresponding side-effect. (Incidentally, this function is also sometimes pronounced `unsafePerformIO`.) GHC implicitly calls `magicallyExecuteIO` on the result of your program’s `main` function, as well as on expressions written in GHCi.

However, without using `magicallyExecuteIO`, evaluating one of the `IO` constructors like `PutStrLn` doesn’t do anything. In this implementation, it would just work like any other data constructor:

```
ghci> Just (PutStrLn "hello!")
Just (PutStrLn "hello!") :: Maybe (IO ())
```

(I’ve wrapped it with `Just` to prevent GHCi from running the `IO` action.)

Of course, GHC’s actual `IO` type isn’t implemented this way, but that’s really just an implementation detail. Evaluating an `IO a` value doesn’t cause a side-effect to happen any more than evaluating a `Maybe a` value does. Only `magicallyExecuteIO` can do that.