# Understanding Type of IO () in `let` Expression

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
λ: let f = putStrLn "foo" in 42
42
```

What is `f`'s type? Why does `"foo"` not get printed before showing the result of `42`?

Lastly, why doesn't the following work?

```
λ: :t f

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: ‘f’
```

Comment: You might want to read about [`let` vs `<-`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28624408/3234959). It is not the exact issue you are having now, but it might help.

Comment: Read [Why can't I force an IO action with seq?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20324446/510937) for a bit more info on evaluating vs executing IO actions.

Answer (score 13):

> What is `f`'s type?

As you have correctly identified, it is `IO ()` which can be thought of as an IO action that returns nothing useful (`()`)

> Why does "foo" not get printed before showing the result of `42`?

Haskell is lazily evaluated, but even `seq` is not enough in this case. An IO action will only be performed in the REPL if the expression returns the IO action. An IO action will only be performed in a program if it's returned by `main`. However, there are ways to get around this limitation.

> Lastly, why doesn't the following work?

Haskell's `let` names a value within the scope of an expression, so after the expression has been evaluated `f` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 10):

`let f = ...` simply defines `f`, and does not "run" anything. It is vaguely similar to a definition of a new function in imperative programming.

Your full code `let f = putStrLn "foo" in 42` could be loosely translated to

```
{
  function f() {
     print("foo");
  }
  return 42;
}
```

You wouldn't expect the above to print anything, right?

By comparison, `let f = putStrLn "foo" in do f; f; return 42` is similar to

```
{
  function f() {
     print("foo");
  }
  f();
  f();
  return 42;
}
```

The correspondence is not perfect, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 7):

`f` will be of type `IO ()`.

"foo" is not printed because `f` is not 'binded' to real world. (I can't say this is a friendly explanation. If this sounds nonsense, you may want to refer some tutorial to catch the idea of Monad and lazy evaluation).

`let name = value in (scope)` makes the value available in, but not out of the scope, so `:t` won't find it in ghci's top level scope.

`let` without `in` makes it available to `:t` (this code is only valid in ghci):

```
> let f = putStrLn "foo"
> :t f
f :: IO ()
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two things going on here.

First, consider

```
let x = sum [1..1000000] in 42
```

Haskell is *lazy*. Since we don't actually do anything with `x`, it is never computed. (Which is just as well, because it would be mildly slow.) Indeed, if you compile this, the compiler will see that `x` is never used, and delete it (i.e., not generate any compiled code for it).

Second, calling `putStrLn` does not actually *print* anything. Rather, it returns `IO ()`, which you can think of as a kind of "I/O command object". Merely having a command object is different from *executing* the it. By design, the only way to "execute" an I/O command object is to return it from `main`. At least, it is in a complete program; GHCi has the helpful feature that if you enter an expression that returns an I/O command object, GHCi will execute it for you.

Your expression returns 42; again, `f` isn't used, so it doesn't do anything.

As `chi` rightly points out, it's a bit like declaring a local (zero-argument) function but never calling it. You wouldn't expect to see any output.

You can also do something like

```
actions = [print 5, print 6, print 7, print 8]
```

This creates a list of I/O command objects. But, again, it does not *execute* any of them.

Typically when you write a function that does I/O, it's a do-block that chains everything into one giant I/O command object and returns it to the caller. In that case, you don't really need to understand or thing about this distinction between *defining* a command object and *executing* it. But the distinction is still there.

It's perhaps easier to see this with a monad that has an explicit run-function. For example, `runST` takes an ST command object, runs it, and gives you back the answer. But (say) `newSTVar`, by itself, does nothing but construct an ST command; you have to `runST` that before anything actually "happens".